# Commonality analyses in linear mixed-effect models in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, multicollinearity

Unfortunately I am nobody's statistician and my question might seem a bit trivial! Also, I was not sure if my question would belong better here or on StackOverflow.

I was wondering how to cope with collinearity within a linear mixed-effect model. I have found great resources for commonality analyses (and particularly the package R 'yhat' developed by Nimon and co.), however, I was unable to find any R function that could compute commonality coefficient for predictor variables when the fitted model is of class lme or lmer (i.e., when using a linear mixed-effect model instead of simple linear model without any random effect).

Therefore, I was wondering if there were any special features to consider, when copying with non-independent fixed variables with mixed-effect models ?

How do I obtain commonality coefficients for fixed predictors while taking random factors into account?

Thank you all for you suggestions!

All the best!

Comment: What is the purpose if your model ? Inference or prediction ? colinearity isn't necessarily a problem for prediction.

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you for your answer! I would like to decipher the relative influence, in terms of variance partition, of two highly linked X and Y explanatory variables on a set of observations Z. Therefore I think this has more to do with inference. The problem is that really do not know how to deal with collinearity while considering the random effect.